# Convert a numpy array of lists to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

I have some data which is stored as a numpy array with `dtype=object`, and I would like to extract one column of lists and convert it to a numpy array.  It seems like a simple problem, but the only way I've found to solve it is to recast the entire thing as a list of lists and then recast it as a numpy array.  Is there a more pythonic approach?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']], [2, ['a', 'b', 'c']]], dtype=object)
arr = arr[:, 1]

print(arr)
# [['a', 'b', 'c'] ['a', 'b', 'c']]

type(arr)
# numpy.ndarray
type(arr[0])
# list

arr.shape
# (2,)
```

Recasting the array as `dtype=str` raises a `ValueError` since it is trying to convert each list to a string.

```
arr.astype(str)
# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

It is possible to rebuild the entire array as a list of lists and then cast it as a numpy array, but this seems like a roundabout way.

```
arr_2 = np.array(list(arr))

type(arr_2)
# numpy.ndarray
type(arr_2[0])
# numpy.ndarray

arr_2.shape
# (2, 3)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A object array is little more than a glorified (or debased) list.  The elements of the array are pointers to those list objects.  Most operations on such an array involve list iteration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though going by way of lists is faster than by way of `vstack`:

```
In [1617]: timeit np.array(arr[:,1].tolist())
...
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 µs per loop
In [1618]: timeit np.vstack(arr[:,1])
...
10000 loops, best of 3: 54.1 µs per loop
```

`vstack` is doing:

```
np.concatenate([np.atleast_2d(a) for a in arr[:,1]],axis=0)
```

Some alternatives:

```
In [1627]: timeit np.array([a for a in arr[:,1]])
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.6 µs per loop
In [1629]: timeit np.stack(arr[:,1],axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 µs per loop
```

Keep in mind that the object array just contains pointers to the lists which are else where in memory.  While the 2d nature of `arr` makes it easy to select the 2nd column, `arr[:,1]` is effectively a list of lists.  And most operations on it treat it as such.  Things like `reshape` don't cross that `object` boundary.

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to use stacking operations with something like [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) -

```
np.vstack(arr[:, 1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [234]: arr
Out[234]: 
array([[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']],
       [2, ['a', 'b', 'c']]], dtype=object)

In [235]: arr[:,1]
Out[235]: array([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], dtype=object)

In [236]: np.vstack(arr[:, 1])
Out[236]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['a', 'b', 'c']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

I believe `np.vstack` would internally use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate). So, to directly use it, we would have -

```
np.concatenate(arr[:, 1]).reshape(len(arr),-1)
```