# Numpy array of numpy arrays has 1D shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of arrays (A and B). They look something like this when printed:

A:

```
[array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0]) array([1, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 1]) array([0, 0, 0])
 array([1, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 1]) array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0]) array([1, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 1]) array([0, 0, 0])]
```

B:

```
[[  4.302135e-01   4.320091e-01   4.302135e-01   4.302135e-01
    1.172584e+08]
 [  4.097128e-01   4.097128e-01   4.077675e-01   4.077675e-01
    4.397120e+07]
 [  3.796353e-01   3.796353e-01   3.778396e-01   3.778396e-01
    2.643200e+07]
 [  3.871173e-01   3.890626e-01   3.871173e-01   3.871173e-01
    2.161040e+07]
 [  3.984899e-01   4.002856e-01   3.984899e-01   3.984899e-01
    1.836240e+07]
 [  4.227315e-01   4.246768e-01   4.227315e-01   4.227315e-01
    1.215760e+07]
 [  4.433817e-01   4.451774e-01   4.433817e-01   4.433817e-01
    9.340800e+06]
 [  4.620867e-01   4.638823e-01   4.620867e-01   4.620867e-01
    1.173760e+07]]
```

`type(A)`, `type(A[0])`, `type(B)`, `type(B[0])` are all `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

However, `A.shape` is `(20,)`, while `B.shape` is `(8, 5)`.

Question 1: Why is `A.shape` one-dimensional, and how do I make it two-dimensional like `B.shape`? They're both arrays of arrays, right?

Question 2, possibly related to Q1: Why does printing `A` show the calls of `array()`, while printing `B` doesn't, and why do the elements of the subarrays of `B` not have commas in-between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the `dtype` of each array? One is an array of arrays, the other a 2D array of floats.

Comment: That's my question -- how do I make the array of arrays into a 2D array of ints/floats?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`A.dtype` is `O`, object, `B.dtype` is `float`.

`A` is a 1d array that contains objects, which happen to be arrays.  They could just as well be lists or None`.

`B` is a 2d array of floats.  Indexing one row of `B` gives a 1d array.

So `A[0]` and `B[0]` can appear to produce the same thing, but the selection process is different.

Try `np.concatenate(A)`, or `np.vstack(A)`.  Both of these then treat `A` as a list of arrays, and join them either in 1 or 2d.

Converting object arrays to regular comes up quite often.

[Converting a 3D List to a 3D NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289943/converting-a-3d-list-to-a-3d-numpy-array)
is a little more general that what you need, but gives a lot of useful information.

also

[Convert a numpy array of lists to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250501/convert-a-numpy-array-of-lists-to-a-numpy-array)

==================

```
In [28]: A=np.empty((5,),object)
In [31]: A
Out[31]: array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [32]: for i in range(5):A[i]=np.zeros((3,),int)
In [33]: A
Out[33]: 
array([array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0]),
       array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0])], dtype=object)
In [34]: print(A)
[array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0])]
In [35]: np.vstack(A)
Out[35]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

## Edit

```
np.stack(A)
```

can join the arrays on a new leading axis.

If the subarrays differ in shape, these 'stack' functions will raise an error.  It's up to you to find the problem array(s).

Comment: Huh, I missed that answer... Thank you!