# Pandas dataframe to 2D numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'histogram' : [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The length of the histograms are always the same (2 in this example case).

[image]

and I would like to convert the 'histogram' column into a 2D numpy array to feed into a neural net. The preferred output is:

```
output_array = np.array(d["histogram"])
```

i.e.:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

however when I try:

```
df["histogram"].to_numpy()
```

the results is an array of lists instead of numpy array of arrays:

```
array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4]), list([5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

this is problematic for neural nets as I have to specify the dimensions/shape.

I try to solve the issue by casting as numpy array:

```
df["histogram_arrays"] = df["histogram"].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
df["histogram_arrays"].to_numpy()
```

which returns a 1D array of arrays and not the 2D array.

```
array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

How can I get the histograms into a 2D array?

Comment: If your input is incorrect, you'll have to cast it some way. But have you actually experienced that using apply is too slow for your dataset? That is, have you tried on a part of your dataset?

Comment: Also: do you want an array of arrays, or a two-dimensional array? The last item you list is *not* a two-dimensional array: it is a one-dimensional array of objects (which happen to be arrays, but that doesn't mean the entire thing is a two-dimensional array).

Comment: you are right, no I need it as a 2D array. let me edit the question.

Comment: Does that also mean it is *guaranteed* that the individual lists in the input are all of the same length (for the example, that would be 2)?

Comment: always same lengths (histogram bin counts) and no NaNs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a numpy array of lists to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250501/convert-a-numpy-array-of-lists-to-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```py
np.vstack(df['histogram'])
```

Comment: beautiful! Thx!

Answer (score 5):

Your question is essentially: how do I convert a NumPy array of (identically-sized) lists to a two-dimensional NumPy array.

That makes it a (near) duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250501/convert-a-numpy-array-of-lists-to-a-numpy-array), but since your actual question is somewhat hidden, I'll put an answer here anyway.

Use `numpy.vstack`:

```
>>> data = df['histogram'].to_numpy()
>>> data
array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4]), list([5, 6])], dtype=object)
>>> data = np.vstack(data)
>>> data.dtype, data.shape
(dtype('int64'), (3, 2))
>>> data
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```